# Check an object in a list of values

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

First, I would like to mention I am to automated testing.
I want to add a test case to Robot Framework which will let me choose from a list (which can change).
I have problem with creating keywords to do this.

Can somebody give me a tips to do this?

1. I have a list, but the values can change. I need to check values inside the list the list.
2. There is a value in the list that I would like to change.

Edit: The questions applies the list on web page.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Ideally please remember to post approached you tried and errors you already faced.

Comment: Are you asking about automating a list of values on a web page, or an actual python list object?

Comment: I am asking about values on a web page, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In your test case you'll need to import the library Collections.

To check a value in a list you can use the keyword

```
 list should contain value    @{MyList}    Value
```

If you want to set a value in the list to something else you can use the keyword

```
 set list value    @{MyList}    1    Value
```

If you want to learn more about these keywords you can find them here.
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html